# Is it possible to set up a mysql environment on Azure that stays within the $50 credit budget for Vs Pro subscription?

Tags: azure, azure-database-mysql

TL;DR: Is there a cheap way to set MySql up in Azure, so that i can keep the sandbox environment going monthly within those $50? (App Service + MySql db server)

I've been trying to set up a .Net MySql sandbox environment on Azure for the credits that comes along with my VS pro subscription.

Currently it looks like this:
[image]

The "Azure Database for MySql" is set to lowest settings possible (a basic Gen 5, with 1 core, 1024GB)
There is 6 databases running on the mysql server,

The App Service plan is set to the lowest standard pricing tier (S1), to be able to mess around with deployment slots.

And then i have two App Services set up, on that App Service plan.

But after about 1 week (maybe a few more days), its already drained most of the $50 (350DKK). There is a scheduler invoking some code every minute, but other than that, its have just done some light testing with local instance on my pc, connected to that mysql db. So I'm puzzled, that it has already drained those $50 (350dkk).
[image]

Is there a cheaper way to set MySql up in Azure, so that i can keep the sandbox environment going monthly within those $50?
I can live with lowering the app service plan, to a free basic, so that I dont have the Deployment Slots, but that would seemingly only have postponed the draining of the $50.

**Edit:**
This is what the compute vs storage distribution looks like:
[image]

Comment: Well you pay for vCores, and you pay for Storage, and you pay for Backup. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/pricing/details/mysql/ So check your storage and backup costs?

Comment: I added the compute vs storage distribution ratio. It would seem that the storage is much higher than anticipated, so I looked into it. I did the mistake of leaving the storage size at 1024 Gb when i provisioned the MySql server, because it looks like im getting billed for every Gb of those 1024 that i provisioned, eventhough I'm only using around 1Gb of actual space.
I guess i'll just have to redo it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use MySQL in-app. In this scenario, MySQL server runs on the same resources side by side with your web app. This is recommended for development purposes and has no additional cost.

You specify the option during provisioning. E.g. search the marketplace for 'MySQL', pick the 'Web App + MySQL option', click Create, and make sure you switch the database provider from 'Azure Database for MySQL' to 'In-App MySQL'.

It's not intended for production and autoscaling won't work, but there is a one-click option to export MySQL databases created this way to a production server.

See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2017/03/06/announcing-general-availability-for-mysql-in-app/ for more details.

Comment: That does indeed sound like a much better solution, as long as it supports multiple databases. I also found it odd, that it was such a steep step up in price from mssql to mysql. I'll go test it out, Thank you.